# Java i/o program error throwFor(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, io

i'm making a program that views a text file and prints it to the console in eclipse. One of the lines in the text file looks like this...

> A.Matthews 4 7 3 10 14 50

when running the program, I get an error like this..
[image]

and this is the program

```
import java.io.*;    // for File
import java.util.*;  // for Scanner

public class MapleLeafLab {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("mapleleafscoring.txt"));
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        String name = lineScan.next(); // e.g. "Eric"
        String rest = lineScan.next();
        int GP = lineScan.nextInt();          // e.g. 456
        int G = lineScan.nextInt();
        int A = lineScan.nextInt();
        int P = lineScan.nextInt();
        int S = lineScan.nextInt();
        Double SS = lineScan.nextDouble();



        System.out.println(name+rest+" "+GP+" "+G+" "+A+" "+P+" "+S+" "+SS);

        //System.out.println(name + " (ID#" + id + ") worked " +
        // sum + " hours (" + average + " hours/day)");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the cause. But you don't need to define new `Scanner`s inside the loop. One solution can be to read the file line by line and then use `split` to separate items in each line.

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase. And if you want human readers, avoid using single character names. They are beyond meaningless.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Javadoc for Scanner:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
>
> ```
> public double nextDouble()
> ```
>
> Scans the next token of the input as a double... If the next token matches the Float regular expression defined above
>   then the token is converted into a double value...
>
> ```
> Returns:
>     the double scanned from the input 
> Throws:
>     InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range
>     NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted
>     IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
> ```

You're getting `NoSuchElementException` because you're trying to read 8 tokens from a 7-token line.

```
A.Matthews => name
4 => rest
7 => GP 
3 => G 
10 => A 
14 => P 
50 => S
SS =>  NoSuchElementException
```